# Change Default Photo Aspect Ratio in iOS

Tags: camera, ios

Is there a way to set the default photo aspect ratio to 3:2 (from 4:3) in the default camera app in iOs?  I know it can be done using different photo apps, and I know that photos can be cropped to a variety of aspect ratios after they’ve been taken. But I’m looking for a way to set it before taking photos, using the default camera app.

Comment: I believe you can not change the aspect ration by default but as per Rich Mogull comment that we can see the 4:3 landscaped photo in landscape orientation by first zooming in and then zooming out on the photo. it sounds crazy but works

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately, with iOS where it is right now, this is not possible. We have watched progressive improvements over time with the default camera app but there are still quite a number of limitations regarding "defaults" in the camera app.

Comment: Thanks.  That's what I thought.  An acquaintance was telling me it was possible.  I looked thoroughly for the option and couldn't find it.  But I wanted official confirmation, since my acquaintance had been so insistent.  I'd like to vote up your answer but don't have a high enough rep. yet.